# Login Authentication and session in JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, web

'

```
<head>

    <title>Reprint</title>    

    <script>

        function addDate1() {
            date1 = new Date();
            var month = date1.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = date1.getDate();
            var year = date1.getFullYear();

            if (document.getElementById('date1').value == '') {
                document.getElementById('date1').value = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
            }
        }
        function addDate() {
            date = new Date();
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = date.getDate();
            var year = date.getFullYear();

            if (document.getElementById('date').value == '') {
                document.getElementById('date').value = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .btn_hover:hover{

            color: darkblue ;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body onload="addDate();
            addDate1()" style="background-color: aliceblue;" >
    <table align="" border="1">
        <tr align="">
            <td  >
                <h3 align="center" >Reprint Request Form <img  src="sarasavi.png" />  </h3>
                    <%
                        Date dNow = new Date();
                        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy.MM.dd");
                        out.print("<h4 align=\"center\">" + ft.format(dNow) + "</h4>");
                    %>  

            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h6 >
                    Enter ISBN or Scan the Barcode <i style="color: #545454" class=" icon-barcode"></i>
                </h6>
                <input id="isbn" type="text" placeholder="ISBN "/>

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul class=" tabs left  " >
                    <li><a href="#tabr1" >Stores</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabr2">Publishing Department</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabr3">Printing Department</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabr4">Director</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- End Tabs -->

                <!-- Stores -->
                <form action="####" method="Post"> 
                    <div id="tabr1" class="tab-content">
                        <!-- HALF & HALF -->

                        <div class=" col_6">
                            <label for="text1" style=" font-size: 16px;">Title  </label><br/>
                            <input id="text1" type="text" placeholder="Title" style="width: 355px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/>
                            <label for="text2" style=" font-size: 16px;">Author  </label><br/>
                            <input id="text2" type="text" placeholder="Author" style="width: 355px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/>
                            <label for="text3" style=" font-size: 16px;">Price   </label></span> <br/>
                            <input id="text3" type="text" placeholder="price" style="width: 95px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/><br/>

                            <!-- Radio -->
                            <label style=" font-size: 16px;">Move</label><br/><br/>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" />
                            <label for="radio1" class="inline">Fast</label><br/>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" />
                            <label for="radio2" class="inline">Medium</label><br/>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" />
                            <label for="radio3" class="inline">Slow</label><br/>
                            <!-- Radio -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="col_6">
                            <label for="text4" style=" font-size: 16px;">Stock in hand </label> <br/>
                            <input id="text4" type="text" placeholder="" style="width: 100px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/>
                            <label style=" font-size: 16px;">Last GRN Date</label><br/>
                            <input type="date" ><br/><br/>
                            <label for="text5" style=" font-size: 16px;">Last GRN Quantity </label></span> <br/>
                            <input id="text5" type="text" placeholder="Qty" style="width: 100px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/><br/>

                            <input type="submit" value="Save"  class="btn_hover"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="submit" value="Reset" class="btn_hover" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- Stores -->

                <!-- Publishing Department -->
                <form action="####" method="Post">
                    <div id="tabr2" class="tab-content">
                        <div class="col_4">
                            <!-- Check box -->
                            <input type="checkbox" id="check1" />
                            <label for="check1" class="inline" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;" >Informed the Author </label><br/><br/><br/>
                            <!-- Check box -->
                            <!-- Table sortable -->
                            <label style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;"> Last Print </label> <br/><br/>
                            <table class="sortable" border='1'>
                                <thead><tr>
                                        <th>Print</th>
                                        <th>Date</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                    </tr></thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Item1</td>
                                        <td>Item2</td>
                                        <td>Item3</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Item1</td>
                                        <td>Item2</td>
                                        <td>Item3</td>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- Table sortable -->
                            <br/><br/>
                            <label for="text6" style=" font-size: 16px;">Printer  </label><br/>
                            <input id="text6" type="text" placeholder="Type Printer Name" style="width: 355px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/>
                            <!-- Select -->
                            <label for="select1">Paper Type</label> <br/>
                            <select id="select1">
                                <option value="0">- Choose a Paper Type -</option>
                                <option value="1">Bank Paper</option>
                                <option value="2">Book Printing Paper </option>
                                <option value="3">Art Paper</option>
                                <option value="4">Bulk</option>
                            </select>
                            <!-- Select -->
                            <br/><br/>
                            <label for="text7" style=" font-size: 16px;">Delivery for Printing  </label><br/>
                            <input id="text7" type="text" placeholder="Type here" style="width: 355px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/>

                            <label for="text8" style=" font-size: 16px;">Quantity Suggested</label><br/>
                            <input id="text8" type="text" placeholder="Type here" style="width: 355px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/> 
                        </div>

                        <div class="col_6" style="padding-left: 100px;">
                            <label style=" font-size: 16px;">Date</label><br/>
                            <input type="text" id="date1" readonly="true " ><br/><br/> 
                            <label for="text9" style=" font-size: 16px;">Altered Page Numbers </label></span> <br/>
                            <input id="text9" type="text" placeholder="Eg-: 4 , 5 , 6 , 34" style="width: 355px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/><br/>
                            <!-- Check box -->
                            <input type="checkbox" id="check2" />
                            <label for="check2" class="inline" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">Sample Copies </label><br/><br/><br/>
                            <!-- Check box -->
                            <label for="text10" style=" font-size: 16px;">Altered Tracing (No.s) </label> <br/>
                            <input id="text10" type="text" placeholder="" style="width: 355px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/>

                            <label style=" font-size: 16px;">Book Cover</label><br/><br/>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" />
                            <label for="radio4" class="inline">Same Cover</label><br/><br/>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio5" />
                            <label for="radio5" class="inline">New Cover</label><br/><br/><br/>

                            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn_hover"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="submit" value="Reset" class="btn_hover" />
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </form>
                <!-- Publishing Department -->
                <form action="####" method="Post"> 
                    <!-- Printing Department -->
                    <div id="tabr3" class="tab-content">
                        <div class="col_4">
                            <!-- Select2 -->
                            <label for="select2">Size</label> <br/>
                            <select id="select2">
                                <option value="0">- Choose a Size -</option>
                                <option value="1">SD 1/8</option>
                                <option value="2">D 1/8</option>
                                <option value="3">D 1/4</option>
                                <option value="4">Cr 1/8</option>
                                <option value="5">Cr 1/4</option>
                                <option value="6">A4</option>
                                <option value="7">A5</option>
                                <option value="8">B4</option>
                            </select><br/><br/><br/>
                            <!-- Select2 -->  
                            <label style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">No. of Pages</label><br/><br/>
                            <label>Black & White -</label>
                            <input type="text"  id="text11"style="width: 100px; height: 28px;" ><br/><br/>
                            <label style="padding-right: 45px">Colour -</label>
                            <input type="text" id="text12 "style="width: 100px; height: 28px;" ><br/><br/><br/>

                            <label style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;"> Last Production Cost</label><br/><br/>
                            <!-- Table sortable2 -->
                            <table class="sortable" border='1'>
                                <thead><tr>
                                        <th>Year</th>
                                        <th>Qty</th>
                                        <th>Cost</th>
                                        <th>Unit Cost</th>
                                    </tr></thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Item1</td>
                                        <td>Item2</td>
                                        <td>Item3</td>
                                        <td>Item4</td>
                                    </tr>

                            </table><br/><br/>
                            <!-- Table sortable2 -->

                            <label style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;"> Estimated Printing Cost</label><br/><br/>
                            <label for="text13" style=" font-size: 16px;">Quantity</label> <br/>
                            <input id="text13" type="text" placeholder="" style="width: 155px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/>
                            <label for="text14" style=" font-size: 16px;">Cost</label> <br/>
                            <input id="text14" type="text" placeholder="" style="width: 155px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/>
                            <label for="text15" style=" font-size: 16px;">Unit Cost</label> <br/>
                            <input id="text15" type="text" placeholder="" style="width: 155px; height: 28px;" readonly="true" /><br/><br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col_3">
                            <!-- Select3 -->
                            <label for="select2">Paper</label> <br/>
                            <select id="select3">
                                <option value="0">- Choose a Paper -</option>
                                <option value="1">60 gsm</option>
                                <option value="2">70 gsm</option>
                                <option value="3">80 gsm</option>
                                <option value="4">100 gsm</option>
                                <option value="5">120 gsm</option>
                                <option value="6">150 gsm</option>
                            </select><br/><br/>
                            <!-- Select3 -->  
                            <!-- Select4 -->
                            <label for="select4">Binding</label> <br/>
                            <select id="select4">
                                <option value="0">- Choose a Binding Methode   -</option>
                                <option value="1">Hard Binding</option>
                                <option value="2">Perfect Binding</option>
                                <option value="3">Suddle Binding</option>
                                <option value="4">Thread Binding/Perfect Binding</option>

                            </select><br/><br/>

                            <!-- Select4 -->  
                            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                            <input type="submit" value="Save"  class="btn_hover"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="submit" value="Reset" class="btn_hover" />

                        </div>
                        <div class="col_3">
                            <label style=" font-size: 16px;">Date</label><br/>
                            <input type="text" id="date" readonly="true" ><br/><br/>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Printing Department -->
                </form>
                <form action="####" method="Post"> 
                    <div id="tabr4" class="tab-content">
                        <div class="col_6">
                            <label for="text16" style=" font-size: 16px;">Present Price  </label><br/>
                            <input id="text16" type="text" placeholder="current Price" style="width: 355px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/>
                            <label for="text17" style=" font-size: 16px;">Revise Price  </label><br/>
                            <input id="text17" type="text" placeholder="new Price" style="width: 355px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/>
                            <label for="text18" style=" font-size: 16px;">Quantity   </label></span> <br/>
                            <input id="text18" type="text" placeholder="Qty" style="width: 355px; height: 28px;" /><br/><br/><br/>

                            <input type="submit" value="Approve"  class="btn_hover"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn_hover" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="submit" value="Reset" class="btn_hover" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col_4">
                            <!-- Textarea -->
                            <label for="textarea1" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;"> Remark</label><br/>
                            <textarea id="textarea1" placeholder="Type Here" style="width: 650px; height: 200px;" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </form>

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <!-- Tabs  -->

</body>
```

'

i have made a little webapp in Java using jsp and am having a little problem with Login Authentication..

1. i have 4 different users. have 4 tabs in a jsp page
2. i need to give them the limited access to Tabs.

eg-director (can see all the tabs)
    officer 1 (can see only have accesses to 3 of tabs  )
    officer 2 (can see only have accesses to 2 of tabs  )
    officer 3 (can see only have accesses to 1 of tabs  )

it is like a security clearance
i tried to so many ways and failed and i am thinking to do that with passing a Boolean to Database and give the access levels 
for that i need a help if it is with a small sample log in project that will be very help full for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this way out,

After successful login, save user type in session. 
Then in jsp add following conditions for role.

let's say for example, We want to block access of Tab 4 for 'officer 2'.
Then in jsp for Tab 4 , add below condition. and like wise in other jsp's also.

```
<c:if test="${role== 'officer 2'}">
  <jsp: forward page="../invalidAccess.html"/>
</c:if>
```

alternatively, You can make use of Filters to do same. Filters are more preferred over earlier way.

Comment: from where i get the role ?? from my database or else where? and where should i put this code into ma div ??

Comment: Fetch role name from database while validating user credentials(in java . ie, servlet or action class). And add this as session attribute.

Comment: Can you do me a favor a little help coz am running out of time to submit this

Comment: shall i mail it to you ??

Comment: i tried to amend the codes but there are some errors with that

Comment: this is ma index page